# Order of Set Operations (Quotient and Product)

Tags: soft-question, notation, grassmannian

This comes up a lot when discussing Grassmannian manifolds, or at least it seems to me. Anyway, if someone writes something like $$\mathbb{RP}^n = O(n+1)/O(n)\times O(1) $$ does the right hand side mean $$O(n+1)/ \ [O(n)\times O(1) ]? \quad or\quad [O(n+1)/O(n)]\times O(1)? $$ Does it not matter in general? I.e. are the two alternatives I gave in general isomorphic (as differentiable manifolds or otherwise)?

I know that for numbers $a/bc$ means $a/(bc)$ (PEMDAS), but generally speaking it's best not to use atrocious notation like that for which one has to think about how to interpret it.

Comment: Seems like the set theory tag is rather irrelevant here, and the whatever-tag suitable for Grassmannian manifold is. Because I'd attribute this largely to convention in a particular field. I don't even know what $O(n)$ even denotes here, so I'm devoid of context as to "in which way reading this makes sense".

Comment: The correct one is the one you listed on the left.  Note that $O(1) = \{1, -1\}$.  So, the one you listed on the right would not be connected.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 This is a good mnemonic -- thank you!